# Shell script prompt after java connection

Tags: linux, bash, shell, java, shell-script

I am trying to put a prompt in the middle of a shell script that starts java processes, however the prompt always gets executed first because of the delay in the java connections. Is there a way I can hold off the prompt to not execute until after the java processes are connected and started?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Starting java processes in the background
java .... &
java .... &
java .... &

# Prompt user
echo -n "Would you like to run the script? (y/n) --> "
read answer
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a wait command in bash, that lets you wait for the termination of a process, but since you're waiting for something to happen while the program is still running, I suggest you use `sleep` to wait a predefined amount of time:

```
# Sleep 5 seconds
sleep 5
# or...
sleep 5s

# Same for minutes (m), hours (h) and so on
```

Just be aware, that if the Java programs takes longer than your defined time, it won't work.